# Firebase: SIgn in/up via GitHub using the same button

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-admin

I want to allow users to sign in/up via GitHub using firebase by clicking on the same button.

I create a new authentication for every user in the server side. 
With the little piece of code, I'm able to detect if either the user is new or not:

```py
const provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
        if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
             // The user is new
        } else {
             // The user is old
        }
```

But, when the function signInWithPopup is called, if the user is a new user, a new authentication is automatically created for him. How can I avoid this? 
And if the user is already authenticate, how can the user sign in from the client side? Where is the link between the authentication done from the back end with the user that wants to sign in the front end?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how OAuth works. If you use an authentication provider like GitHub, they handle auth flow for you. The only thing that you are left with on the frontend side is an idToken with your identity, basic profile info, and a signature so you can as a user using this token. There's no distinction between sign up/sign in actions.

As you have noticed, Firebase is an extra layer in this flow, it creates an account for a user who signs in for the first time. But there's no user limit or extra payment so I wouldn't bother too much about these extra accounts. You might consider periodical cleanups if you care about the security here.

If you want to actually check if the user exists you have to use `firebase-admin` e.g. in a Firebase Function before the `signInWithPopup` is called. But still, unless you want to prevent users from signing up, you can hook your server logic into [functions.auth.user().onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) trigger.

To answer your last question, when the user is already signed in, you'll get the user object in `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` when a page is loaded. Login state is stored by Firebase.js so once you have called `signInWithPopup`, you don't need extra steps.

Comment: The problem is I want to customize the authentication by defining the user id of the Firebase auth user. That is using firebase admin, I create a new user with this code: auth.ImportUserRecord(
            uid=submission["id"],
            email=submission["email"],
            provider_data=[  # user with Google provider
                auth.UserProvider(
                    uid=submission["display_name"],
                    email=submission["email"],
                    provider_id='github.com'
                )
But I don't know how to sign in the very same user.

Comment: May I know why it's so crucial to you to have user uid's set by you? It's not very common scenario thus not well supported. AFAIK in your current scenario you'd have to create user before calling `signInWithPopup`, but at this stage you don't know user email so they would have to pass it manually for you.

Comment: So you say that it's not possible?

Comment: I actually implemented the email/password sign in like that, so I wanted to custom the id when signing in via GitHub. Actually the custom id is the country id of the user. It's still PK and make the code design better. What are the solutions?

Comment: I still don't understand what is your custom user ID. Country ID would be the same for various users so I guess that it's only a part of your URL? Anyway, you still didn't answer the question, what is it for that you need these country ids in the user ID? Without that, I cannot help you.